# How to reverse an ELF compiled in Android NDK with OLLVM obfuscation

Tags: android, root, reverse, deobfuscation

I got an Android root exploit from a malicious apk. But all the functions in the ELF are striped and I find it was compiled with OLLVM(https://github.com/obfuscator-llvm/obfuscator).How can I figure out what vulnerability it expoloit. Anyone has some tips about how to deal with such ELFs？
As far as I know, this obfuscator is also popular in CTF games.